# Big Endian vs Little Endian 2 ASCII characters per memory address

Tags: endianness

This is homework that is asking how ORENTM would be stored in memory if you stored two ASCII characters per memory location.  All the examples show one byte ordering.  I am wondering if in the little Endian the ASCII character order would be revesed so the at 102 it would be 52 4F instead of 4F 52.  Also does anybody have a good reference to read about how this type of storage would work.

[image: ASCII and HEX equivalent]

[image: Memory Storage]

Comment: Endianness doesn't affect the order of bytes in a string, they are stored in the same order in both architectures.

Comment: Missing information: the size of your memory locations. (It is 16 bits, no?) And, the endianness of your CPU's bit/integer operations. Also, to add meaning to your question, you would write the value stored at a memory location as an integer (hexadecimal or otherwise), rather than byte by byte because when people write a sequence of bytes they have usually already baked out the endianness.